# WebStorm - Cannot find names of built-in js classes in TypeScript 3

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, tslint

I have updated my app's TypeScript package to version `~3.1.6` from version 2.

After I've done so, it looks like WebStorm doesn't recognize some of the built-in classes (such as `Promise`, `Date`, `JSON`, etc...)

[image: Cannot find name 'Promise']

[image: Cannot find name 'JSON']

More than that, it looks like it doesn't recognize an array as an array. Therefore, it says the `.forEach` does not exists. Of course, it doesn't happen only with `.forEach`.

[image: Property 'forEach' does not exists on type '{}']

Hard typing doesn't help either:

[image: Property 'forEach' does not exists on type '{}']

The TypeScript and the TSLint settings look fine:

[image: Typescript settings]

[image: TSLint settings]

It looks like only WebStorm has a hard time with it. The files are being compiled successfully without any errors.

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Errors come from Typescript compiler, not from the IDE; looks like either the compiler is misconfigured or typescript installation is broken and required d.ts files can't be found. If re-installing `typescript` module doesn't help, please provide your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @lena I have updated my answer with the `tsconfig.json` as you requested.

Comment: If I ``ctr``l+``click`` the names, I **do** get redirected to the `lib.es5.d.ts` file.

Comment: works fine for me using your config. did you try re-installing node_modules?

Comment: You're right. reinstalling the whole node_modules did the trick. For some reason, I re-installed the global `typescript`.

Comment: Thaks!. I resolved by upgrading my global typescript. `yarn global add typescript`.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later, reinstalling node_modules (as suggested in the comments on the question did not work for me). However, restarting the typescript service in Webstorm did.

[image: "Restart Typescript Service" command in Webstorm]

Comment: I do not know what you refer to. Apart from "above" being an unreliable reference (because order of display is individually configurabe) there is no other answer whatsoever.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).